# How to calculate the Memstores, WAL & Block Cache in HBASE?

Tags: hbase

Suppose in HBase we have 3 Region servers, 3 regions and 2 column families.How many Memstores, Block Cache & WAL  are possible

Answer (score 0):

#### Memstore count

Each column family of region has 1 memstore. 3 regions * 2 col families = 6 memstores. But in case of [in-memory compactions](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#inmemory_compaction) things become more complicated. Please refer to official doc.

#### Block Cache sizing

[Block Cache](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#block.cache) size is hard to predict because it depends on too many parameters. Block Cache contains entries for:

1. blocks of HFiles(which contain your data) which was accessed by your scan/get requests(if it wasn't explicitly disabled in request). Default size is 64K.
2. blocks of catalog tables(e.g. hbase:meta)
3. blocks of HFiles indexes(default size of index block defined by `hfile.index.block.max.size`)
4. blocks of HFile's bloom filters(default size of Bloom filter block defined by
   `io.storefile.bloom.block.size`)
   Also block cache has few different implementations with it's own configuration parameters. Please refer to official docs for tuning knobs.
   More info about type of HFile blocks can be found [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_hfile_format_2).

#### WAL

Each RegionServer has 1 active WAL and N rolled WAL files. WAL rolling happens:

- periodically
- when log file reach max size
- fsync is slow for current WAL file
- WAL file has low replica count on HDFS
  Rolled WAL file can be removed if all write operations defined in this file was persisted into HFiles. Such cleanup based on tracked `seqnum`'s of each region's column family(description of `seqnum` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348159/why-do-we-flush-all-memstores-in-hbase-at-the-same-time/62690840#62690840)).